# Office 365 API not working after CTP2 to CTP3 Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2013, office365, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Office 365 API in a Visual Studio Multi device hybrid project stopped working after I upgrade from CTP2 to Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3. How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to download and install the latest [Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013](http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2013) or [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15b85e6-69a7-4fdf-adda-a38066bb5155). There was change in O365 service and accordingly JS library which makes REST call to O365 was also updated. Create new project and add the required service, this will add latest JS library to project under 'services' folder. Replace services folder in your existing project with this new. You have to also change namespace to match the new library. Most of the API name and parameter are same but make sure the API which you were using is there in new JS library. You can find more detail on O365 API [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/platform-development-overview)

Comment: I've done all that but still no go. After I put my login credentilas to connect to azure it shows connection refused error